# Prove $ X = \left(\begin{array} &A & C \\ 0 & B \end{array} \right) $ is invertible iff A and B both are.

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Suppose $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, $B$ is a $m \times m$ matrix, and $C$ is a $n \times m$ matrix. Prove  $ X = \left(\begin{array} &A & C \\ 0 & B \end{array} \right) $  is invertible iff A and B are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(1)$ Suppose $A,B$ are both invertible. What is the most obvious candidate for an inverse of your matrix?

$(2)$ Suppose your matrix is invertible. Write its inverse in blocks as your original matrix. What is the obvious choice for inverses of $A$ and $B$?

**ADD** A slicker solution would be to note $$\det  \begin{pmatrix}
   A & C  \\ 
   {0} & B  \end{pmatrix}=\det A\cdot \det B $$

Comment: Would this be the matrix that satisfies part 1? $$ \left(\begin{array} &{A^{-1}} & {-{A^{-1}}C{B^{-1}}} \\ 0 & {B^{-1}} \end{array} \right) $$

Comment: @user39493 Yes, that is the solution.

Comment: I much prefer the slicker solution.

Comment: @user39493 It is a good solution, but it's useful to consider the problem from multiple perspectives. In principal, you can prove the particular statement you are thinking about by considering any of the conditions equivalent to invertibility laid out in the Invertible Matrix Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix has full rank if and only if both $A$ and $B$ do.

OR

The columns of your matrix are linearly independent if and only if the columns of $A$ and $B$ are.

Comment: Could you think of a hint that assumes the student is not familiar with rank?